# Security disabler doesn't operate in context of Unlock-Item comandlet?

Tags: powershell-extensions

Writing a script to allow editors to unlock an item locked by another user I used

```
New-UsingBlock(New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler"){
$item | Unlock-Item
}
```

This didn't raise errors, but didn't unlock the item

Directly calling the Unlock() method did work though

```
New-UsingBlock(New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler"){
    $item.Locking.Unlock()
    }
```

Is there a reason for this?

Note: this is only the briefest of outline, other possible differences include retrieving the item to unlock inside or outside the security disabler block, and getting multiple items (using a foreach-object for unlocking by second method, piping the results of the query using the first).

Comment: Two things to try. Add `-PassThru` to unlock command, if data is returned then it's not exiting on the security check. Second, try user switcher.

Comment: I'll try with -PassThru, but the second version of the code is working fine, so I'm mainly just curious.